# Quantification Logic, symbolization

Tags: logic

Nothing healthful is either illaudable or jejune. How will I symbolize this one? $\lnot(\exists x) [Hx \land (Ix \lor Jx)]$. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually, yes, that's right. Equivalently, $(\forall x)\,(H(x)\to (\neg\,I(x)\land\neg\,J(x))$. (Why?:)